# Passing authentication from api to api [net core]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I created have two different APIs projects with two different database one for storing users and authentication other for storing products. I managed to create authentication using json web tokens and I stored them in httpcontext.session and after user login in using my api I inject jwt token in request header. My question is how can I use my auth with jwt from users api for products api? I wanna make that only auth users can post products. How products api gonna detect auth from users api?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your products api jwt authentication with same validation parameters as you have in your token generator

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //development only!
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        //params
                });
```

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```